# C - How to pass _self into a function thats assigned to a pointer

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, declaration, implicit-conversion

I'm probably getting mixed up as I'm a OO developer. I'm trying to have several instances that call a common method.

I want to somehow reference the caller in a function that is assigned thus...

header

```
typedef struct _Part Part;
struct _Part {
  void (*move)();
}
```

code

```
void move(Part p) {
}

void main() {
  Part part1;
  part1.move = move(part1); <-- Won't compile

  part1.move();
}
```

Is there some way of making this work or do I have to stop thinking like an OO dev and just call the `move` method directly, passing in the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the structure like

```
typedef struct _Part Part;
struct _Part {
  void (*move)( Part);
};
```

and just write

```
part1.move = move;
```

The function designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function.

And then write

```
part1.move( part1 );
```

Comment: Wouldn't i just be better off calling `move (part1`)? I was trying to avoid passing in the variable

Comment: @TedTrippin You may call the function directly. But in this case the data member of the structure is redundant.

Comment: I know, hence my original question. If it's not possible to achieve my goal I'll just remove it and call it directly. I'm just too use to the OO world.